# Solution of $f'(t) = f(t)^2$ when $f: U \subset \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{C}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, complex-numbers

> Let $f: U \subset \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{C}$ be a continuously differentiable function (that is, its component functions are continuously differentiable) defined on a suitable open subset $U$ of $\mathbb{R}$, such that $f'(t) = f(t)^2, \forall t \in U$.

Can  we determine the solution to the above equation by "abstracting" of the real-valued case? By this I mean that if we say $f(t) = x(t) + iy(t)$, then $f' = f^2$ implies that
$$
x'(t) = x(t)^2 - y(t)^2, y'(t) = 2x(t)y(t), \forall t \in U, 
$$
so by existence and uniqueness, we above system has a unique solution for each initial condition, so we can determine $f$ from the real ODEs.

However, can we determine the solution using only the complex system, i.e. can we say that
$$
f(t) = \frac{1}{c-t}, \forall t \in U
$$
for some $c \in \mathbb{C}$ and then determine $x$ and $y$ from this?

I do not think that the above is correct. When I plug the real system into Wolfram Alpha, the solution is completely different.

**Edit**

I was thinking about this question when I tried to "merge" the real and the complex case.

I know that if $f$ would have been defined on a "bigger" subset of $\mathbb{C}$ (that would not include only real numbers) and if it were holomorphic, then we could the existence and uniqueness and standard results from the complex case to get the solution.

Comment: What are the real and imaginary parts of $f(t) = 1/(c-t)$? And do they satisfy the system of ODEs?

Comment: Well, if $c = a+bi$, then $$\frac{1}{c-t} = \frac{a-t}{(a-t)^2 + b^2} - i\frac{b}{(a-t)^2 + b^2}, $$ and I the real and imaginary parts do not satisfy the real ODE system. However, where does my "reasoning" of determining the solution in this complex case go wrong? Can't we use the same results as in the real case? And if so, how would one go about determining $f$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $f(t) = F(t,c)$ is an analytic function of $(t,c)$ in some (open, connected) domain $D \subseteq \mathbb C^2$ containing the product of real intervals $(a,b) \times (c_0, c_1)$ and satisfies the differential equation
$f'(t) = G(f(t),t)$ there for real $t$ and $c$, where $G$ is an analytic function of two variables, then  by analytic continuation it satisfies the differential equation in all of $D$.  Thus a general solution that works for real $c$ will also work for complex $c$.  In particular this applies to your differential equation: $f' = f^2$: the general solution $F(t,c) = 1/(c-t)$ is always a solution to the differential equation on $\{(t,c): t \ne c\}$.

Comment: I see; you are right, we can extend the differential equation on a bigger (complex) domain. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps, you didn’t check the computations carefully because with $$x(t)=\frac{a-t}{(a-t)^2+b^2}\,,~\,~\,~\,~ y(t)=\frac{-b} {(a-t)^2+b^2}\,$$ then we have
$$x’(t)=\frac{(a-t)^2-b^2}{((a-t)^2+b^2)^2}=x(t)^2-y(t)^2\,,$$
$$y’(t)=\frac{-2b(a-t)}{((a-t)^2+b^2)^2}=2x(t)y(t)\,,$$
which is in perfect agreement.

Comment: You are right, I made some computation mistakes. Thank you!